# How can I keep my Embermage alive?

Tags: torchlight-2

The Embermage class, unlike the other three available classes in Torchlight 2, seems to lack any decent defensive spells:

- **Death's Bounty** is arguably the most useful defensive spell, allowing you to recoup health and mana from enemies under this spell's effect
- **Immolation Aura** can absorb 5%, 10%, or 15% damage based on the tier
- **Elemental Boon** boosts elemental resistances
- **Prismatic Rift** will randomly teleport enemies away when they hit

Other than these, I don't see any other spells that help my character stay alive. So my question is simple: **what's the best way to keep an Embermage alive?** Is having the best offense the only option for this class? I've found that Embermages can have a tough time in acts 3 and 4, especially in large mob situations (one-shot kills seem to be a staple of this class, at least in my experience). What are some tips to keep my Embermage alive and well?

Comment: You've probably thought of this, but I'd invest in particularly good armour, for a start.  I haven't played much Embermage so I don't have much else to offer, sorry.

Comment: Do not get hit!

Comment: You have yet to discover Ice Prison and Frost Phase.  The ice mage is one of the strongest builds in this game.  Frost Phase is a very fast teleport.  Ice Prison can be used to keep enemies out or to lock them in.  An Embermage should be trying to avoid, not absorb damage.